# Running spark action in oozie with sqlContext

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I am trying to run a spark action in Oozie workflow. it runs fine until I try to access hive external table via spark. My workflow:

```
<action name="SparkJob">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobtracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${namenode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <name>name</name>
            <class>classname</class>
            <jar>jar file</jar>
            <spark-opts>--conf spark.yarn.queue=${queuename_nonp} --conf spark.ui.port=5050</spark-opts>
    </spark>
    <ok to="EMAIL_SUCCESS"/>
    <error to="EMAIL_FAILURE"/>
</action>
```

Once the Oozie job failed, I checked the yarn log with the application id given in Oozie output. the error mentioned there is-

---

```
2019-06-20 17:14:56,602 [Driver] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster  - User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier use found

use instance_name
^
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier use found

use instance_name.
^
```

---

The code which this error is referring is below spark queries. I am using these spark queries as jar in the workflow.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_unixtime, regexp_replace}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions

object loadHiveTable {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-transformation-001")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("avro_file")
    val temptable = "temp_emp"
    df4.registerTempTable(temptable)
    val tempquery = "select * from temp_emp"
    val result = sqlContext.sql(tempquery)
    result.show()
    val setQuery = "use instance_name"
    sqlContext.sql(setQuery)
    val queryCreateTable = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEES_Spark(\n   EMPLOYEE_ID INT,\n   FIRST_NAME STRING,\n   LAST_NAME STRING,\n   EMAIL STRING,\n   PHONE_NUMBER STRING,\n   HIRE_DATE DATE,\n   JOB_ID STRING,\n   SALARY DECIMAL(8,2),\n   COMMISSION_PCT DECIMAL(2,2),\n   MANAGER_ID INT\n   )\n   PARTITIONED BY (DEPARTMENT_ID INT)\n   LOCATION 'path'\n   tblproperties (\"`skip.header.line.count`\"=\"1\")"
    sqlContext.sql(queryCreateTable)
    sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true")
    sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict")
    val insertQuery = "insert overwrite table employees_spark partition (department_id) select * from temp_emp"
    sqlContext.sql(insertQuery)
}
}
```

I want to know what is wrong with this when running as a jar file in Oozie.

I am running the whole spark query in spark shell and getting correct result till the final step. I can view the data getting entered in hive external table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use HiveContext instead of SQLContext.

Comment: In my environment we can use either.. it’s set up. And I am using sqlContext when running this through spark-she’ll. And it’s not giving any error

Comment: this is an odd behavior. I believe it is caused by having "keywords" as column-names. Sometimes I've seen that the spark-shell is more forgiving vs running it as an application. All keywords used as column names should be quoted with `` so that they are treated as column names and not keywords. Example EMAIL becomes `EMAIL` in your query. Also I suggest you to use `` for table name and database name. I hope this helps.

Up Vote Answer if works for you. Good Luck

Comment: it is actually recognizing the columns and db name. anyway i tried with your suggestion and it gave same error. I am transferring the content of a data frame using temp table. i am not able to create a temp table using hiveContext and not able to create table in hive with sqlContext (only when running through JAR file). since i am using two context, it is not recognizing temp table from sqlcontext in hivecontext.

Comment: which spark version are you using ?

Comment: I am using spark 1.6. i am going via file instead of temp table. i think that will be easier